# For $f\in L^2$, the function $(-\Delta)^{-1/2}f$ is in $L^2 + L^\infty$.

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, integral-inequality

Suppose $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ is a smooth domain. Let $-\Delta_\Omega$ denote the Dirichlet Laplacian on this domain (considered as a densely defined self-adjoint operator).

**Question:** For $f\in L^2(\Omega)$, is the function $V_f := (-\Delta_\Omega)^{-1/2}f$ representable as a sum of a $L^2(\Omega)$ and a $L^\infty(\Omega)$ function?

**Motivation:** I am interested into spectral properties of Hamiltonians $H_f = -\Delta_\Omega + V_f$. For this I obviously have to ensure self-adjointness of $H_f$ first, which should be possible via the Kato-Rellich theorem. We could apply the latter if we know $V_f \in (L^2\! +\! L^\infty)(\Omega)$.

**Ideas:** One may use kernel estimates $(-\Delta_\Omega)^{-1/2}(x,y) \lesssim \lvert x-y \rvert^{-2}$ in combination with the Hardy-Littlewood-Sobolev inequality to obtain for example $\| V_f \|_2 \lesssim \| f \|_{6/5}$, which would imply the claim in the case of a bounded domain. However, I am also interested into the unbounded case. Probably one should use linearity of $V_f$ in $f$ in order to truncate $f$ into a compactly supported part plus rest and then...?

Comment: Why should it? For an unbounded domain, $0$ may be an element of the spectrum, so $(-\Delta_\Omega)^{-1/2}$ is not well-defined as a an operator on $L^2$ in the sense of functional calculus..

Comment: It seems to be true for $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^3$ via Fourier transform. Maybe one can use some comparison principle to generlize this to domains.

Comment: Okay so Fourier transform or equivalently the HLS-inequality should give $V_f \in L^6$. Do we have $L^6 \in L^2 + L^\infty$?

Comment: When $\Omega$ is bounded, we have $L^6\subseteq L^2$, so yes.

Comment: You don't need a bounded domain, you always have $L^r\subset L^p+L^q$ if $p\leq r\leq q$.

Comment: Btw, the Fourier transform argument I had in mind was to write $\hat V_f=|\xi|^{-1}\hat f 1_{|\xi|\leq 1}+|\xi|^{-1}\hat f 1_{|\xi|>1}$. The first summand is in $L^1$, hence its inverse Fourier transform is in $L^\infty$, while the second summand is in $L^2$ and thus also its inverse Fourier transform. This seems a little simpler than the full HLS inequality.

Comment: Ah cool, yes in comparison with the kernel estimate I quoted, this should also proof the fact for the general domain!

Comment: Ah maybe that's confusing: I meant "smoothly bounded" in the sense of a smooth boundary. I will fix that